# Boost the performance when importing an excel to MATLAB

Tags: excel, performance, matlab, import

Given that I have a excel file with 101 Sheets, now I would like to import all the sheets to MATLAB.

#### My trial

```matlab
tic
sheet_names = sheetnames('./data/head_101.xls');
n_rows = numel(sheet_names);
rows_data = cell(n_rows, 1);

rows_max_idx = ones(1, n_rows);

% import all the sheets
for i = 1:numel(sheet_names)
    row_data = readmatrix('./data/head_101.xls', 'Sheet', sheet_names(i));
    rows_data{i} = row_data;
    [n_points, ~] = size(row_data);
    rows_max_idx(i) = n_points - 1;
end
```

which gives

> elapsed 7.587835 seconds (Oops, it is time-consuming!!)

#### Question

If there is a more efficient way to read Excel files more efficiently?

Comment: Please provide an example of what sort of data is in your document. Is is just numeric data in a specific range of cells?